# Function pointers comparison

Tags: c++, function, callback

I want to write a function which behavior should be different depending on which function is an argument. As I can see, I have to compare argument function pointer and other function pointer. Second functions declared in the same class.

I thought i can do something like this:

```
void TestClass::testFunction(void inputFunction(functionArgument))
{
  if (*inputFunction== &TestClass::classFunction) {

  }
}
```

But apparently not.

Can I do that in the first place, and if I can, how?

Comment: What is `requestedFunction`? Where does is come from? Probably `requestedFunction` should be `inputFunction`. What is `functionArgument`?

Comment: [Yes you can](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q695R8mB64vVWgnf). Please provide [mcve], including code that reproduces your problem and error message you get.

Comment: You don't want to do this. This is called 'state orientation', and it was abandoned in the 1960s.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a pointer to function or member function, not the function itself.

```
// Accepts a pointer to function
void TestClass::testFunction(void (*requestedFunction)(int argument))
{
    if (requestedFunction == &TestClass::classFunction)
        ...
}

// Accepts a pointer to member function
void TestClass::testFunction(void (TestClass::*requestedFunction)(int argument))
{
    if (requestedFunction == &TestClass::classFunction)
        ...
}
```

You can simplify the syntax if you have a `typedef` for the function pointer type.

```
typedef void (*function_t)(int argument);

// Accepts a pointer to function
void TestClass::testFunction(function_t requestedFunction)
{
    if (requestedFunction == &TestClass::classFunction)
        ...
}

typedef void (TestClass::*member_function_t)(int argument);

// Accepts a pointer to member function
void TestClass::testFunction(member_function_t requestedFunction)
{
    if (requestedFunction == &TestClass::classFunction)
        ...
}
```

Note, however, that comparing pointers to functions can break if the function is defined in multiple translation units, which can happen when the function is defined in multiple shared libraries and/or executable.